# BATCH - Remove some characters from filename

Tags: csv, batch-file

I've files with this name:

```
FirstPart_SecondPart_ThirdPart.zip_FourthPart_FifthPartX.csv
```

where X is a one-digit number.
It should be renamed via batch scripting as:

```
FirstPart_SecondPart_ThirdPart.zip_FifthPartX.csv
```

So I'd like to remove the FourthPart. Please note that all the parts ALWAYS HAVE the same lenght. FirstPart is always 7 digits, SecondPart is always 9 digits...etc...

Here is what I've tried:

```
ren \*.zip_*FifthPart?.csv *.zip_FifthPart?.csv
```

But it does not work.

Please any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) to split and rebuild the file names:

```cmd
for /F "delims= eol=|" %%F in ('dir /B /A:-D "*_*_*_*_*.csv"') do (
    for /F "tokens=1-4* delims=_ eol=_" %%A in ("%%F") do (
        ren "%%F" "%%A_%%B_%%C_%%E"
    )
)
```

Given that none of the parts contain underscores (`_`) on their own and none of them are empty, a single loop is sufficient:

```cmd
for /F "tokens=1-4* delims=_ eol=_" %%A in ('dir /B /A:-D "*_*_*_*_*.csv"') do (
    ren "%%A_%%B_%%C_%%D_%%E" "%%A_%%B_%%C_%%E"
)
```

---

Here is an approach with an additional filter for file names using [`findstr`](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) in order to exclude files that do not match the name specifications:

```cmd
for /F "tokens=1-4* delims=_ eol=_" %%A in ('
    dir /B /A:-D "*_*_*_*_*.csv" ^| findstr /I "^[^_][^_]*_[^_][^_]*_[^_][^_]*_[^_][^_]*_[^_].*\.csv$"
') do (
    ren "%%A_%%B_%%C_%%D_%%E" "%%A_%%B_%%C_%%E"
)
```

Comment: Could you please explain the reason for either the outer `For` loop, or for two `For` loops?

Comment: @Compo, the outer `for /F` loop returns the original file names unedited; using a single `for /F` loop could fail if there are files with two consecutive underscores in their names (remember `for /F` treats adjacent delimiters as one); in case no such files exist, one loop is sufficient...

Comment: @Compo, I added another approach using a single loop, which requires an additional filter (`findstr`) to work safely for all arbitrary file names...

Comment: …but the OP stated that all files followed the same length and layout and you agreed at the top of your answer that none of them is empty meaning no consecutive/adjacent delimiters.

Comment: It's better although technically you've not really clarified it, you've just taken my supplied answer and included it after your initial 'over complicated' answer was accepted.

Comment: Thanks for down-voting and not commenting!

Answer (score 2):

*Within the appropriate directory*

…at the Command prompt:

```bat
For /F "EOL=_Tokens=1-4*Delims=_" %A In ('Dir/B/A-D "*_*_*_*_*.csv"') Do @Ren "%A_%B_%C_%D_%E" "%A_%B_%C_%E"
```

…in a batch file:

```bat
@For /F "EOL=_Tokens=1-4*Delims=_" %%A In ('Dir/B/A-D "*_*_*_*_*.csv"'
) Do @Ren "%%A_%%B_%%C_%%D_%%E" "%%A_%%B_%%C_%%E"
```

Because you are already certain of the file name format and character numbers I feel that the best approach would be to utilise `Where` instead of `Dir`.

For example, *in a batch file*:

FirstPart is always 7 digits, SecondPart is always 9 digits, ThirdPart is always 6 digits, FourthPart is always 5 digits and FifthPart is always 8 digits.

```bat
@For /F "EOL=_Tokens=1-4*Delims=_" %%A In (
    'Where .:"???????_?????????_??????_?????_????????.csv"'
) Do @Ren "%%A_%%B_%%C_%%D_%%E" "%%A_%%B_%%C_%%E"
```

Comment: @Leo91, please consider revising your acceptance vote should you agree that my answer better fulfills the requirements; Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities to solve this:

(1) As all parts always have the same length, you can just use substrings to cut the `FourthPart_` part:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('DIR /B *.csv') DO (
    SET new_filename=%%G
    SET new_filename=!new_filename:~0,35!!new_filename:~46!
    ECHO REN "%%G" "!new_filename!"
)
```

(2) Alternatively, if `FourthPart_` is a static string, you might also get away with removing the `FourthPart_` using search & replace:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('DIR /B *.csv') DO (
    SET new_filename=%%G
    SET new_filename=!new_filename:FourthPart_=!
    ECHO REN "%%G" "!new_filename!"
)
```

These batch files will only output the commands to be issued. Remove the `ECHO` once you've inspected the output and you're confident it does what you want.